# how to verify current open files on specific service

Tags: systemd, rhel, ulimit, systemctl, open-files

on our rhel server 7.6 version we have the following systemctl service

```
/etc/systemd/system/test-infra.service
```

and the value of LimitNOFILE is

```
systemctl show test-infra.service | grep LimitNOFILE
LimitNOFILE=65535
```

so I assume the number of open files is max 65535 per this service

is it possible to print the current of open files that are used by this service?

or how to show how many files this service is using?

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify the executable run by this service (in the `ExecStart=` statement of the `test-infra.service` file), you should be able to do this using

```
lsof | grep executable name
```

possibly followed by `| wc -l` if you just want to count the files.